# How to Center a Circuitikz Drawing Inside Standalone Without a Border

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, standalone

I have created my custom electric component named `myIC` using the `circuitikzgit.sty` library ([download link](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzgit.sty)). `myIC` has three pins labeled `PinA`, `PinB`, and `PinC`. I defined this component within the `pgfdeclareshape` environment, allowing me to easily incorporate it into a `circuitikz` environment. I'm quite satisfied with the outcome, but I encountered an issue when compiling the code. As you can see, the drawing isn't centered as expected. You can observe the difference between `border=2cm` and `border=0cm` in the two outputs below.

**Question: How can I center my circuit without displaying a border, similar to the behavior typically seen in the** `\documentclass{standalone}`**?**

**CODE**:

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikzgit}

\pgfdeclareshape{myIC}{
    
    % define saved anchor
    % ----------------------------------------
      \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    
    % define Connectors relative to the center
    % ----------------------------------------
      % Pin A:
      \savedanchor\myICpinA{\pgfpoint{-30}{10}}
      \anchor{}{\myICpinA}
      % Pin B:
      \savedanchor\myICpinB{\pgfpoint{-30}{-10}}
      \anchor{}{\myICpinB}
      % Pin C:
      \savedanchor\myICpinC{\pgfpoint{30}{0}}
      \anchor{}{\myICpinC}
    
    \foregroundpath{
        
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-30}{-30}}{\pgfpoint{30}{30}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        
        \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinA}]{PinA}
        \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinB}]{PinB}
        \pgftext[right, at={\myICpinC}]{PinC}
        
        }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{circuitikz}
                \draw (0,0) node[myIC] {};
            \end{circuitikz}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT** (`border=2cm`):
[image]

**OUTPUT** (`border=0cm`):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`circuitikz` environment is an alias for `tikzpicture`. Using both, you are nesting tikzpictures, which is a no-no.

Change your main body to:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) node[myIC] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and you'll have a center thing:

[image]

(Anyway, you are using no `circuitikz` here,  given that you define a shape yourself... but I suppose you have more things here).

Complete code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\pgfdeclareshape{myIC}{
    
    % define saved anchor
    % ----------------------------------------
      \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    
    % define Connectors relative to the center
    % ----------------------------------------
      % Pin A:
      \savedanchor\myICpinA{\pgfpoint{-30}{10}}
      \anchor{}{\myICpinA}
      % Pin B:
      \savedanchor\myICpinB{\pgfpoint{-30}{-10}}
      \anchor{}{\myICpinB}
      % Pin C:
      \savedanchor\myICpinC{\pgfpoint{30}{0}}
      \anchor{}{\myICpinC}
    
    \foregroundpath{
        
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-30}{-30}}{\pgfpoint{30}{30}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        
        \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinA}]{PinA}
        \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinB}]{PinB}
        \pgftext[right, at={\myICpinC}]{PinC}
        
        }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) node[myIC] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: THANKS a lot for your help! It works :)